# Get Only keys from a Dictionary includes Arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this Dictionary that have two arrays on it :

```
    var myOptions: [[String:String]] = [
    [
        "1)About something": "some text here",
        "2)Useful Advices": "some text here",
        "3)Not to do": "some text here",
        "4)Users Agreements": "some text here"
    ],
    [
        "5)About something else": "some text here",
        "6)Useless Advices": "some text here",
        "7)To do": "some text here",
        "8)Non Users Agreements": "some text here"
    ]
]
```

And I want to create a new array with only the keys from myOptions array with the keys that I have only on the first array on myOptions array.

so to be specific the new array it may looks like :

```
var keysOnly: [String] = ["1)About something","2)Useful Advices","3)Not to do","4)Users Agreements"]
```

Thank you so much in advance,
Kostis

Comment: Those aren't arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array that contains 2 dictionaries. It sounds like you want the keys from the first dictionary:

```
let keys = Array(myOptions[0].keys)

print(keys)
```

If you want to combine the keys from the 2 dictionaries, and you want to sort the results, you could use @BencePattogato s answer:

```
var keys = myOptions.flatMap({ return $0.keys }).sorted(by: <)
```

But if your keys contains numbers with varying numbers of digits, you won't get the ordering you expect:

```
var myOptions: [[String:String]] = [
  [
    "1)About something": "some text here",
    "2)Useful Advices": "some text here",
    "3)Not to do": "some text here",
    "4)Users Agreements": "some text here"
  ],
  [
    "5)About something else": "some text here",
    "6)Useless Advices": "some text here",
    "7)To do": "some text here",
    "18)Non Users Agreements": "some text here"
  ]
]

var sortedKeys = myOptions.flatMap({ return $0.keys }).sorted(by: <)
```

Would return:

```
1)About something
18)Non Users Agreements
2)Useful Advices
3)Not to do
4)Users Agreements
5)About something else
6)Useless Advices
7)To do
```

(note how 18 sorts between 1 and 2)

You could rewrite the sort like this:

```
var sortedKeys = myOptions.flatMap({ return $0.keys })
  .sorted{ $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending }
```

That would give the results:

```
1)About something
2)Useful Advices
3)Not to do
4)Users Agreements
5)About something else
6)Useless Advices
7)To do
18)Non Users Agreements
```

Which is probably what you want. (By using `compare()` with an `options` setting of `.numeric`, you tell the `Array<String>` `sorted()` method to sort groups of digits in the strings as numeric values.)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it easily with functional programming:

```
var keysOnly: [String] = myOptions.flatMap({ return $0.keys })
```

// The sample output you wrote is only possible accidentally or after a sort, because dictionary is not ordered. You can achieve it in one line like:

```
var keys = myOptions.flatMap { $0.keys }.sorted(by: <)
```

Comment: That messes up the order.

Comment: @shallowThought, there is no order to mess up. The inner structures are dictionaries, which are unordered.

Comment: Ah, got it. Sorry. And thanx @DuncanC.

Comment: @Bence, the OP says he only wants the keys from the first entry. Your solutions combine the keys from both arrays. That's an elegant way to solve that problem, but it's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I thought his output was just a sample, let @kstefanou decide which one to use

Comment: Thank so much all of you guys. The solution of @BencePattogato with the sort is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: To the OP: What did you mean when you said "I want to create a new array with only the keys from myOptions array **with the keys that I have only on the first array on myOptions array**."

Comment: @kstefanou, did you want all 8 keys shown in your example to be included in the output list of keys? An would you want a key "2)Useful Advices to sort before "17)some other key"? (Since 2 is a smaller number than 17?) If so you would need to use a slightly different sort.

Comment: You can use some sugar to clean up the syntax of that flatmap. `myOptions.flatMap { $0.keys }.sorted(by: <)` or even `myOptions.flatMap(\.keys).sorted(by: <)`